# gcc: Linking C library in a C++ app results in "multiple definition of" errors

Tags: c++, gcc, multiple-definition-error

I have a working C library which I want to link to a C++ application using gcc but the linker (g++) is giving me the "multiple definition" error. With a C application and gcc it works.
  The headers defining the interface all contain the:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif
```

I checked the library using the "nm" command and it does have multiple definitions of the method (the method in question is not from the public interface).

My questions are:

1. Why does my library have multiple definitions (some have the T while others have U)?
2. Why it works if the application including the file is a C application (I'm using -Wall to build)?
3. Do I need any special attribute or use a specific file extension to make it work or is the case that I need to go back to programming school :) ?

Paying more attention to the lib.a file I can see that one of the objects is included twice. For example, I have two sections for the same object:

```
 obj1.o
 00000000     T    Method

 obj2.o
 00000000     T    Hello

 obj1.o
 00000000     T    Method
```

I guess this is the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: For clarity. Are the multiple symbols from the public interface of the library (i.e. what's in the header files) or from standard library stuff?

Comment: Are you building with all the same settings? Several settings will cause binaries to be incompatible -- i.e. default calling conventions and the like.

Comment: To Laserallan - Good question. The repeated symbols are from standard library stuff.

Comment: To Billy ONeal - Yes, same settings, just using -I and -L, nothing fancy.

Comment: Where are you using `gcc` and/or `g++` while making the C++ app? Assume you have source files `cLib.c` `cApp.c` and `cppApp.cpp`. If you try this I assume it works? `gcc cLib.c -o cLib.o; gcc cApp.c -o cApp.o; gcc cLib.o cApp.o -o cApp.exe`   But this fails?: `gcc cLib.c -o cLib.o; g++ cppApp.cpp -o cppApp.o; g++ cLib.o cppApp.o -o cppApp.exe`

Comment: To Aaron McDaid -  I believe your example is similar but in my case is more like g++ -Iinclude -Llib -o helloWorld -lmylib.

Comment: In nm, the T means a definition symbol in the text (code) section, the U means an undefined symbol.  So unless you had multiple Ts, the symbols aren't multiply defined in the library itself.  It would help to have the exact, full command line(s) you are using.

Comment: the command line is the one mentioned above: g++ -Iinclude -Llib -o helloWorld helloWorld.cpp -lmylib

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess is that the "#define **BLAHBLAH_H**" and "#ifndef **BLAHBLAH_H** / #endif" set outside the 'extern "C"{}' thing.

Comment: Way too wild :) the methods in question are not public therefore their headers don't need the extern C thing. (at least not as far as I know).

Comment: I'm not really proficient with cpp.  However, in C, the extern keyword simply means the variable/function is declared somewhere and hence, it is declared locally without giving the actual definition.  If nothing else works, it might worth a try.  :P  I look forward to seeing the actual reason & solution.

Answer (score 1):

after playing around I found that actually the whole command line (it's kind of a complex application with an automated compilation and linkage) contained the --whole-archive parameter before the inclusion of the C library. Moving the library after the --no-whole-archive fixed the problem.

Original command

```
   gcc -Wl,**--whole-archive** -l:otherlibs *-Llibpath -l:libname* Wl,**--no-whole-archive** -o myApp hello.c
```

Fixed command

```
   gcc -Wl,**--whole-archive** -l:otherlibs Wl,**--no-whole-archive** *-Llibpath -l:libname* -o myApp hello.c
```

Thank you for everyone's help guys and sorry if I didn't provide enough/accurate information.

Best Regards